# Batch file to close a application in a specific order

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will shutdown PC, (the order is important) let me explain,

This is a touch panel running one application all the time. it has a back UPS hooked up to the PC.

In the event of a power failure the UPS will initiate PC shut down. (provided it has a batch file).

In order to properly shut down, the application must exit from it's exit menu.

So is this event possible? if so, can someone provide some help (I don't know how to code but willing to learn).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Batch files can't interact with GUIs.

Comment: Take a look at `taskkill /?` and `tasklist /?`. Batch files can touch anything the user has privileges for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SomethingDark maybe I can use the touch panels XY position to click on exit?

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for the reply can elaborate on the code a little bit (not a coder here)

Comment: `Taskkill` will signal your application that it should shutdown. Unless your GUI app is poorly written, there shouldn't be any difference between clicking `Exit` on a menu and just sending it a shutdown message. Now `taskkill /f` will forcibly kill the process, which would not allow your app to exit gracefully.

Comment: Please read [ask]. We're not coding service. I gave some clues to research. It's up to you to try them out. Try it manually in a console window first, then configure your UPS service to run that command. It shouldn't need a batch script. If it does, just paste the command that works in a script file and configure the service to call that.

Comment: Sadly, batch doesn't know what a mouse is, so clicking is also out of the question. Like jwdonahue suggests, a regular `taskkill` should make the program exit gracefully (unlike a `taskkill /f` which is closer to UNIX's [kill -9](https://web.archive.org/web/20110730051506/http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter)).